# How do I toggleClass using the code below?

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, onclick

after spending many months diving into PHP, I have a question regarding my code below. I try the expand the bootstrap panel-body however it will only accept addClass and not toggleClass.

I hope you wonderful people can help with this! I like finding mistakes but this is starting to annoy me! I am trying to create a blog (without CMS) from start to end and see how it goes!

PHP ECHO BELOW:

```
echo "

                        <div class='panel panel-default'>
                            <div class='panel-heading'>
                                <h3 class='panel-title'>$title</h3><p class='storefrontNameAnd_Date'>$author $time</p>
                        </div>

                              <div class='panel-body'>
                                <p>$message</p>
                                <button class='btn btn-success btn-reply' style='float:right'>
                                $clickReply
                                </button>
                              </div>

                        </div>

                ";
```

JQUERY BELOW:

```
$(function(){

    $("button").click(function(){


        $(this).parent().closest("div").addClass("replyClicked");

    });

});
```

CSS BELOW:

```
.replyClicked {

  color: red;
  height: 500px;
  transition: all 0.5s;

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to add the class to the `.panel-body` div?

Comment: or to `.panel-default`?

Comment: To the panel-body, I'm trying to adjust the height of the panel-body to then include a HTML input for text.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, I instead reverted to PHP and used MYSQL data 'id' to generate the ID for data-target='#$id' and added data-toggle='collapse' to another part of the box.